# is possible to determine s-t connected in sub linear expected time?

Tags: algorithm, random, time-complexity

My friend claimed there was a algorithm that decides if two node are connected in less than O(n) time for the average case. I asked him how that would work and he said you need to use a random number generator. I tried researching this, but I only found algorithms using the "depth first search", and the only random algorithms reduced space but not time.

This is of particular interest to me as I am using depth first search for the same problem in a small game i am creating. This is why he said I should use this other algorithm to lower the chance of slowdown.

thank you for your time

edit: This is for directed graph

Comment: What is `n` supposed to be?

Comment: the number of nodes in the graph